# Have to install Silverlight in browsers in the future too?

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, plugins, browser

I know that you have to install plugins before you could use them in the web browser.

Will it always be like this for plugins like Silverlight?

Or do you think major browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc) be shipped with it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the odds of it being supplied with those browsers are very slim.  It's not on Google's\Mozilla's priorities and probably will never be (Maybe unless it becomes extremely popular.. But that's a very long shot).
Let's worry about HTML5 full support in all major browser before we're thinking about that..
But do notice that all Windows versions since Vista and Server 2008 do include the WPF runtime libraries, which means they do support Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what the people want and not so much about what Google or Mozilla wants. Majority rules and eventually if enough people want it then it will be preinstalled. It happened for Flash, why not Silverlight?